# How to call a specific cookie is JS

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have 2 cookies in my index page which comes from a user prompt. The cookies are `"user=userinput"` and `"pass=userinput"`. How would I call these cookies to be able to edit DOM HTML?

The code I have setting the cookies is basic `document.cookie = "user=Jeff; path=/pages/"` and `document.cookie = 'pass='+passToCheck+'; path=/pages'`.

So how do I call document.cookie["user="] or document.cookie["pass="], is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Comment: `document.cookie` returns a string, not an object. You simply parse that string into an array by splitting it at the semicolon and then access the array items.